# How to use stored procedure in Linq-to-Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework

I want to know how I can use stored procedures in Linq-to-Entities. My stored procedure is called `SelectEmployee` and table name is `Employee`

For this I added code like this

```
 databaseentity entities = new databaseentity();
 var selectdata = entities.ExecuteStoreQuery<Employee>("SelectEmployee").ToList();
```

but it is not supported `ExecuteStoreQuery`

So please guide me how can I use stored procedures in Linq-to-Entities

Comment: See [Data Read using Stored Procedures](http://entityframeworktutorial.net/data-read-using-stored-procedure.aspx) for an **extensive** tutorial on how to do this. Would have found this ***easily*** when Googling ... or see [one of the ***many*** SO question (and answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity+framework+stored+procedure) on that topic

Comment: which version of entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple steps:

1. Add your stored procedure to the edmx.
2. You will find that sp in Model Browser
3. Right click on stored procedure and say `Add Function Import`
4. use it by `entities.SelectEmployee()`

Comment: As a slight 'gotcha' make sure your application user has execute permissions to the SP else you won't be able to find it, to add it

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the following two short articles

http://entityframeworktutorial.net/data-read-using-stored-procedure.aspx

http://entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx